# Can't view another activity in kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-intent, android-activity

It moves to the activity but I get an empty page

MainActivit.kt

This is the block I use to move

```
binding.fab2.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(this, InfoActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
```

The other activity

I removed the package

```
package ...

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

import android.os.Bundle

import com.m.anwer.astudy.databinding.ActivityInfoBinding

public class InfoActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var _binding: ActivityInfoBinding? = null

    

    private val binding: ActivityInfoBinding

      get() = checkNotNull(_binding) { "Activity has been destroyed" }

    

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        _binding = ActivityInfoBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

        setContentView(binding.root)

        

    }

    

    override fun onDestroy() {

        super.onDestroy()

        _binding = null

    }


}
```

activity_info.xml

All seems good

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    tools:context=".InfoActivity">

    

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout

        android:id="@+id/appbar"

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Dark.ActionBar"

        app:layout_behavior="com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout$Behavior">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar

            android:id="@+id/toolbar"

            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"

            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.MaterialComponents.Light" />

        

        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/tv1"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:text="Welcome"

            android:textSize="18sp"

            android:textStyle="bold"

            android:layout_margin="16dp"

            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"

            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayou
t>
```

Manifest

I added the another activity manually

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<manifest 

    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <application 

        android:allowBackup="true" 

        android:icon="@drawable/graduate_hat" 

        android:roundIcon="@drawable/graduate_hat" 

        android:label="@string/app_name" 

        android:supportsRtl="true" 

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity 

            android:name=".MainActivity" 

            android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>

                <action 

                    android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category 

                    android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            </intent-filter>

        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".InfoActivity" />

    </application>

</manifest>
```

All seems good but I don't know what is wrong

I have tried it without binding and the same problem. Tried to move to MainActivity from the same Activity and worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the `activity_info.xml` nesting might be the problem.

You have

```
ConstraintLayout
    AppBarLayout
        MaterialToolBar
        TextView
```

Your `Textview` has constraint layout attributes but isn't in the constraint layout. The `AppBarLayout` doesn't have constraint layout attributes.

I think you're looking for something like

```
CoordinatorLayout
    AppBarLayout
        MaterialToolbar
    ConstraintLayout
        TextView (or other content)
```

`AppBarLayout` should cooperate with the `CoordinatorLayout` (for expand/collapse etc.) and the `TextView` should be in the main content area (the `ConstraintLayout`)

For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright 2023 Google LLC.
     SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
-->
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".InfoActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout     
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Welcome"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Thx, it was a mistake